# Changing Google Earth Engine support link text and image

Tags: support

At the bottom of the Google Earth Engine [Data Catalog](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets), there are a number of links to further information and support options. One is a link to [GIS Stack Exchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-earth-engine) with the text and image referring to Stack Overflow:

> [image]
>
> Stack Overflow
>
> Ask questions using the google-earth-engine tag

As we are not Stack Overflow, should we request that the image and text be corrected to refer to GIS Stack Exchange to match the link?

Comment: If you feel you need to reach out to Google Development to make that change please do. We cannot control third-party links or images that are inbound to GIS-SE. But they depend on our user to support their product questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**As of November 5, this is now fixed.**

---

I work on Earth Engine, and I've filed a bug report with this information. Thanks for noticing!

(Some backstory: when we first decided to recommend Stack Exchange as a place to ask questions, the few user questions that existed were fairly evenly split across GIS and SO, and it wasn't as clear that GIS would be the best place to go, since Earth Engine questions are sometimes actually JavaScript (or Python) questions. Probably when we decided to recommend GIS exclusively, we changed all the URLs and forgot some of the text…)